# How to check for when a checkbox is checked in a Userform?

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform, excel-2016

I have a Userform that has a Checkbox. I am able to check the value of it, but it is always `False` whether it is checked or not.

**Update**

This is how the UserForm is being called (This is in another UserForm ):

```
Private Sub AddOutgoingbtn_Click()
    With New AddIncomingForm
        .TopBottom.Value = False
        .Show
        .Repaint
    End With
End Sub
```

**End Update**

I created a sub to look for a change in the value like:

```
Sub TopBottom2_Change()
    With AddOutgoingForm
        If .TopBottom2.Value = True Then TopBottom = True
        If .TopBottom2.Value = False Then TopBottom = False
    End With
End Sub
```

But no matter what I do the `.TopBottom2.Value` is always `False`.

I've put a breakpoint on the `With` line so that I know it is hitting this Sub, then I step through it each time. I open the `UserForm` and check the box, step through and the value is `False`, then I uncheck the box and step through. The value is still `False`.

I am not setting the value in any other way with VBA. I am checking the value in the `UserForms` code, not in any other place.

I have an `If` in a Calculation Module that is looking at this value for when it is true or falses, but it is always false.

Here are all the Properties of the Checkbox:

[image: TopBottom Properties]

Comment: Would be nice if you could [edit] the question to show exactly how you're displaying the form - as explained in my answer (and the linked blog post), it matters very very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> With AddOutgoingForm
> ```

That's referring to the form's *default instance*, which may or may not be the instance that's currently being displayed.

You have two options:

1. At the call site, instead of doing this (or something similar):

   ```
   With New AddOutgoingForm
       .Show
       '...
   End With
   ```

   Do this:

   ```
   AddOutgoingForm.Show
   '...
   ```

   That way you'll be working with the *default instance* and the checkbox value-check should work.

   ...but IMO [that's a very very bad idea](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), because then your form contains code that will only ever work when you're showing the default instance.

---

2. Leave the call site alone, and **NEVER** refer to the *default instance* of a `UserForm` *inside* that form's code-behind. In other words change `With AddOutgoingForm` for `With Me`.

   The `Me` keyword refers to the **current** instance - and *that* is what you want. Doing this will make the form work regardless of what the call site does.

   Alternatively, just drop the `With` block altogether: `With Me` wouldn't be doing anything useful here.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things! Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @ScottCraner not sure they'll care for it, but I replied. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the checkbox is indeed on your user form so just use me or you could use

```
AddOutgoingForm.TopBottom2.Value
```

But let me ask you, where is TopBottom and what is it a Boolean variable or another Checkbox?  Also on the same form?  The Subs are also all in the form?  You have to be calling the form from somewhere so be careful between the worksheet, workbook, module variables.  Is TopBottom a Global variable to the whole project (in a module called Global_Variables with Public in front of it perhaps?)  You may not have access to TopBottom from inside of your form if you are not passing anything in or out.

```
Private Sub TopBottom2_Change()
    If (Me.TopBottom2.Value) = True Then 
         Me.TopBottom.Value = True
    Else
         Me.TopBottom.Value = False
    End If
 End Sub
```

Cheers,
-WWC

Comment: The inline `If` syntax is perfectly legal. `TopBottom2` is rather obviously some control on the form, given how the procedure is rather obviously an event handler for it. This answer is making the wrong assumptions.

Comment: Mat I was asking about **TopBottom** as it is not defined in the scope of the function provided, nothing is passed in, how do you know you have access to it? I realize TopBottom2 is a handler (for assumed renamed checkbox).  It is tough to tell without all the code, hence I recommended the use of **me** (to point to the caller), but I don't see many people using their form templates with the new keyword lately.  Which by the way corresponds to your suggestion. - WWC

Comment: `TopBottom` would be some module variable or global whatever - it's not relevant to OP's problem with the checkbox always being seen as unchecked (which `Me` qualifier fixes indeed) - unless I completely misread the question the OP is about the condition always evaluating to false. FWIW I also see lots of people running into problems because they don't `New` up their form classes and work off default instances: global scope state is evil... See the article I linked to in my post.

Comment: We are on the same page with regard to userforms for sure.
I did want to cover the chance that the OP was actually checking TopBottom and always was getting False (and was interpreting that the checkbox must also always be false, in case it is initialized false and no code runs to update it . . .).  So to get a feel for that trap I was looking to see what its context was.  Thank you for your reconsideration. Cheers, -WWC